# Sharing variables between shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script (let's call it parent.sh) which calls another shell script (child.sh), passing it an argument.

The child script does some work and sets a value in a variable called `create_sql`. I want to access this `create_sql` variable from the parent script which invoked it.

I am calling the child script from within the parent script like this:

`./child.sh "$dictionary"`

and straight afterwards I have the line:

`echo "The resulting create script is: "$create_sql`

However, there is no value being output, however, in the child script I am doing the same thing and the variable is definitely set.

How can I get this to work so that I can read variables created by the child script?

Comment: Succinctly, you can't do that unless you do something like `. ./child.sh "$dictionary"` (or in Bash, mimicking the C shell, `source ./child.sh "$dictionary"`).  This reads and executes the script in the environment of the current shell, but could mess with other variables in the `parent.sh` script — there is no isolation between the scripts.  Otherwise, a child process cannot sanely set the environment of the parent shell.  (If you want to do it insanely, you can have the child shell run a debugger, attach to the parent shell process and set the environment that way — but 'insane' is polite).

Comment: Ok, how can I implement this functionality then? Should I just put the contents of the child script into the parent script? This was my attempt at modularizing the scripts..

Comment: Arguably, the best way is to have the `child.sh` echo the value you want in `$create_sql`, and then you use `create_sql=$(./child.sh "$dictionary")` with no spaces around the assignment operator.

Comment: Child scripts can pass data to parents using exit codes, output streams, files. You could add some more less usual methods (such as signals), but environment variables are basically out. One common method is outputting something that can be `eval`-ed in the parent script (like `ssh-agent`: it will output `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=something; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=something; export SSH_AGENT_PID;` and you would use it as `eval $(ssh-agent ...)` in the parent)

Comment: Oh cool! That actually makes a lot of sense - I'm new to shell scripting and this is really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Succinctly, you can't have a child script set a variable in the parent script unless you do something like:

```
. ./child.sh "$dictionary"
```

(or in Bash, mimicking the C shell, `source ./child.sh "$dictionary"`). This reads and executes the script in the environment of the current shell, but could alter any other variable in the `parent.sh` script; there is no isolation between the scripts. Otherwise, a child process cannot sanely set the environment of the parent shell. (If you want to do it insanely, you can have the child shell run a debugger, attach to the parent shell process and set the environment that way — but calling it 'insane' is being polite).

Arguably, the best way to get output from the child stashed in a variable in the parent script is to have `child.sh` echo the value you want in `$create_sql`, and then you use

```
create_sql=$(./child.sh "$dictionary")
echo "The resulting create script is: $create_sql"
```

with no spaces around the assignment operator.  Note that the `echo` includes the variable inside the double quotes; this will preserve internal spacing (including newlines) in the variable's value.  As written in the question, the variable is flattened into a space-separated stream of 'words' (sequences of non-spaces), losing any internal spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **source** Luke !
source word ( or . ) allows to run a script like if it was in current shell.
beware, your script and the source one are 'married' :-) , sourced script have full access to all variables for the better or the worse...

Other ways implies to modify called script to put is result in a stream format that will be read by caller using `script params | read VAR` or `RESULT=$(SCRIPT params)` and echoing results from your called script